# Multi Stage Contact Form - PHP

Tags: php, forms, contact-form, multi-step

http://webexpedition18.com/download/signup_form_WebExpedition18/

Hi Guys,

The above multi-stage contact form works great for my own project. It looks great and does the trick but i am stumped when trying to get the information submitted via email.

So i have a nice looking form but it wont send any information so is pretty useless to me. Even when i just upload the untouched demo files from the tutorial site, it still doesn't work.

Here's the html i have:

```
<div id="container">
 <form action="contact.php" method="post">
    <div id="first_step">
        <div class="form">
            <label for="full-name">Full Name:</label> <input id="username"
            name="full-name" style="margin-bottom:10px;" type="text" value=
            ""> <label for="telephone">Telephone:</label> <input id=
            "username" name="telephone" style="margin-bottom:10px;" type=
            "text" value=""> <label for="email-address">Email
            Address:</label> <input id="username" name="email-address"
            style="margin-bottom:10px;" type="text" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div><input class="submit" id="submit_first"
        name="submit_first" type="submit" value="Next">
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div id="second_step">
        <div class="form">
            <label for="company-name">Company Name (if you have
            one):</label> <input id="username" name="company-name" style=
            "margin-bottom:10px;" type="text" value=""> <label for=
            "existing-website">Existing Website (if you have one):</label>
            <input id="username" name="existing-website" style=
            "margin-bottom:10px;" type="text" value=""> <label for=
            "existing-domain">What domain would you like the new website to
            be on?</label> <input id="username" name="existing-domain"
            style="margin-bottom:10px;" type="text" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div><input class="submit" id="submit_second"
        name="submit_second" type="submit" value="Next">
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div id="third_step">
        <div class="form">
            <label for="which-package">Which package would you
            like?:</label>

            <p><label><input id="RadioGroup1_0" name="RadioGroup1" type=
            "radio" value="Standard"> Standard</label> <label><input id=
            "RadioGroup1_1" name="RadioGroup1" type="radio" value=
            "Business"> Business</label> <label><input id="RadioGroup1_2"
            name="RadioGroup1" type="radio" value="Professional">
            Professional</label></p><label for="which-template">Which
            template would you like?:</label>

            <p><label><input id="RadioGroup2_0" name="RadioGroup2" type=
            "radio" value="1"> 1</label> <label><input id=
            "RadioGroup2_1" name="RadioGroup2" type="radio" value=
            "2"> 2</label> <label><input id="RadioGroup2_2"
            name="RadioGroup2" type="radio" value="3">
            3</label></p>

            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div><input class="submit" id="submit_third"
        name="submit_third" type="submit" value="Next">
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div id="fourth_step">
        <div class="form">
            <h2>All done ...</h2>

            <p style="margin-top:30px;">Press 'Submit' and we'll send you
            everything you need to get you up and running.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div><input class="send submit" id=
        "submit_fourth" name="submit_fourth" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

The submit button just doesn't do anything. I have tried a number of different php form handler codes in my contact.php file but i still get nothing.

Any help is hugely appreciated guys. I'm getting really desperate now after 6 hours trying with this.

Thank you.

The JS file that comes with the demo is:

```
$(function(){
//original field values
var field_values = {
        //id        :  value
        'username'  : 'username',
        'password'  : 'password',
        'cpassword' : 'password',
        'firstname'  : 'first name',
        'lastname'  : 'last name',
        'email'  : 'email address'
};


//inputfocus
$('input#username').inputfocus({ value: field_values['username'] });
$('input#password').inputfocus({ value: field_values['password'] });
$('input#cpassword').inputfocus({ value: field_values['cpassword'] }); 
$('input#lastname').inputfocus({ value: field_values['lastname'] });
$('input#firstname').inputfocus({ value: field_values['firstname'] });
$('input#email').inputfocus({ value: field_values['email'] }); 




//reset progress bar
$('#progress').css('width','0');
$('#progress_text').html('0% Complete');

//first_step
$('form').submit(function(){ return false; });
$('#submit_first').click(function(){
    //remove classes
    $('#first_step input').removeClass('error').removeClass('valid');

    //ckeck if inputs aren't empty
    var fields = $('#first_step input[type=text], #first_step input[type=password]');
    var error = 0;
    fields.each(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if( value.length<4 || value==field_values[$(this).attr('id')] ) {
            $(this).addClass('error');
            $(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);

            error++;
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('valid');
        }
    });        

    if(!error) {
        if( $('#password').val() != $('#cpassword').val() ) {
                $('#first_step input[type=password]').each(function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('valid').addClass('error');
                    $(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);
                });

                return false;
        } else {   
            //update progress bar
            $('#progress_text').html('33% Complete');
            $('#progress').css('width','113px');

            //slide steps
            $('#first_step').slideUp();
            $('#second_step').slideDown();     
        }               
    } else return false;
});


$('#submit_second').click(function(){
    //remove classes
    $('#second_step input').removeClass('error').removeClass('valid');

    var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;  
    var fields = $('#second_step input[type=text]');
    var error = 0;
    fields.each(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if( value.length<1 || value==field_values[$(this).attr('id')] || (   $(this).attr('id')=='email' && !emailPattern.test(value) ) ) {
            $(this).addClass('error');
            $(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);

            error++;
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('valid');
        }
    });

    if(!error) {
            //update progress bar
            $('#progress_text').html('66% Complete');
            $('#progress').css('width','226px');

            //slide steps
            $('#second_step').slideUp();
            $('#third_step').slideDown();     
    } else return false;

});


$('#submit_third').click(function(){
    //update progress bar
    $('#progress_text').html('100% Complete');
    $('#progress').css('width','339px');

    //prepare the fourth step
    var fields = new Array(
        $('#username').val(),
        $('#password').val(),
        $('#email').val(),
        $('#firstname').val() + ' ' + $('#lastname').val(),
        $('#age').val(),
        $('#gender').val(),
        $('#country').val()                       
    );
    var tr = $('#fourth_step tr');
    tr.each(function(){
        //alert( fields[$(this).index()] )
        $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').html(fields[$(this).index()]);
    });

    //slide steps
    $('#third_step').slideUp();
    $('#fourth_step').slideDown();            
});


$('#submit_fourth').click(function(){
    //send information to server
    alert('Sent. Thank you!');
});

});
```

And the php is used within my contact.php file was:

```
<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'yourname@website.com';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
empty($_POST['email']) || 
empty($_POST['message']))
{
$errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 

if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
$errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
$to = $myemail; 
$email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
" Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Message \n $message"; 

$headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//redirect to the 'thank you' page
header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
} 
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
```

"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact form handler</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- This page is displayed only if there is some error -->
<?php
    echo nl2br($errors);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe if you actually added some PHP. Not anywhere do I see a trace of `contact.php` or any kind of action for the form. If the `action="#"` and you don't have any PHP in your page, then it's not going to do anything.

Comment: This needs heavy unshown javascript to do _anything_.

Comment: Basically any starting points would be hugely appreciated. I have tried amending loads of different contactform handlers to use on this html but i cant get anything to make the submit button work in teh slightest. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`$('form').submit(function(){ return false; });` tells that submit should return false

Comment: //first_step
    $('form').submit(function(){ return false; });
    $('#submit_first').click(function(){

Comment: No it tells that submit should return false indepently of which step it is (It is executed each time $(function() is executed). Try to uncomment it and you will see.

Comment: I tried but it just submits the page and refreshes without going onto the next section (part of the form). Thanks though - Its got me thinking!

Comment: If the page refreshes, the javascript is reloaded and it be in the state as it was before. If you want to reload page after each submit you will have to use ajax (or split the form into separate files)